# How To Get The value of the input by passing a dynamic input name using Xpath?

Tags: python, python-2.7, xpath, python-requests

The working code is like this:

```
csrf = list(set(htmls.xpath("//input[@name='whatever']/@value")))[0]
```

However, I'm trying to get that input name as a parameter passed into the function, in that way I would do something like this:

```
tokenname = sys.argv[2]
```

which gives the value 'whatever', and I want to pass it something like this:

```
csrf = list(set(htmls.xpath("//input[@name="+tokenname+"]/@value")))[0]
```

But it doesn't work that way, anyway to pass a variable in that @name value?

The full code is here:

```
import requests
from lxml import html
import json
import sys

session_requests = requests.session()
login_url = sys.argv[1]
tokenname = sys.argv[2]
result = session_requests.get(login_url)
htmls = html.fromstring(result.text)

csrf = list(set(htmls.xpath("//input[@name={}]/@value".format(tokenname))))[0]

print csrf
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**

Based upon  discussion, looks like you had issues with `"` and escape charcaters.
Use following

```
csrf = list(set(htmls.xpath("//input[@name=\"{}\"]/@value".format(tokenname))))[0]
```

**Old**
You can use `format` as below

```
"//input[@name={}]/@value".format('whatever')
```

From [python doc site](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting)

str.format(*args, **kwargs)

> Perform a string formatting operation. The string on which this method is called can contain literal text or replacement fields delimited by braces {}. Each replacement field contains either the numeric index of a positional argument, or the name of a keyword argument. Returns a copy of the string where each replacement field is replaced with the string value of the corresponding argument.

```
>>> "The sum of 1 + 2 is {0}".format(1+2)
'The sum of 1 + 2 is 3'
```

Comment: you meant something like this : csrf = list(set(htmls.xpath("//input[@name={}]/@value".format(tokenname)) ?

Comment: I did this : csrf = list(set(htmls.xpath("//input[@name={}]/@value".format(tokenname))))[0] Still doesn't work. Same error as before 
string(35) "IndexError: list index out of range"

Comment: the error may be somewhere in entire string. Without more details I can say is try printing entire list without [0] to see if you are receiving any values. or try adding more detailed code to your question.

Comment: Yes, I added the code, when I use the format it doesn't work even if I pass the string into it. However if I do it without using .format and passing a direct string value it works.

Comment: can u try @name="+{}+" as stated in your earlier statement (try to give exact except actual value where you put {}. The .format just performs string substitution.

Comment: This throws an exception "
string(54) "TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'dict' objects"
    "

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138288/discussion-between-anil-m-and-user2906838).